# How to take advantage of Xcode 8 new live previews

Tags: xcode8

I can't find any documentation of how to get interface builder to render UI as it will be at runtime (a new feature as shown [here](https://developer.apple.com/xcode/). Does anyone know how?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This functionality comes for free, without any need to enable it. Rendering iOS content in the Interface Builder canvas now includes effects such as blurs and vibrancy.

If you have custom views, using IBDesignable and IBInspectable (introduced in Xcode 6) are a great way to enable design-time rendering inside IB. Here are some starting points:

- http://help.apple.com/xcode/mac/8.0/#/devf60c1c514
- http://nshipster.com/ibinspectable-ibdesignable/

Comment: I think you have a typo in "...with were introduced...". Also, the link seems to be dead.

Comment: @QuinnTaylor I don't get IBInspectable / IBDesignable controls showing in preview. Is there anything I'm missing. I have my controls in a separate deliverable. They show fine in normal IB.